# How to create a Knowledge mobilisation framework!

Tags: knowledge, framework

I know this question will be rebuked and shut down but I would still like to pick the brains of smart ones!

There are lot of siloes in my company who works across various projects in Salesforce ranging from Mulesoft, Marketing Cloud, CDP , Heroku etc etc. How do you make sure that the knowledge does not just remain in Siloes and may be get mobilised across teams.
How can we mobilise the use cases that different teams have solved?

And how do you create a framework to share or cross train teams on the use cases/elegant solutions that other teams have built so next time when there is a problem to be solved I can piggyback on the solutions that I had learned from other teams and also I can propose/re-sell the use cases to my clients that I learn within my company.

Such a waste opportunity to not have a framework around knowledge sharing.

Answer (score 0):

We do have something around knowledge sharing. It's called [Salesforce Knowledge](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.knowledge_whatis.htm&type=5). You can categorize the Knowledge Articles in various ways, translate them to different languages, host them on a public Knowledge Site through [Help Center](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=sf.networks_help_center_intro.htm&type=5), use them on mobile devices, and so on. It has numerous permissions so you can control who can see, edit, and remove Knowledge Articles, Data Categories, etc.

I'm not sure if it suits your particular needs, and other systems, like Atlassian Confluence is often used to build these kinds of knowledge bases, but I happen to think that Salesforce Knowledge is a decent feature, and it's included in most editions at no extra cost. That said, I'm not sure what the minimum license you'd need to publish Knowledge Articles, so it may not be cost-efficient for your needs. You can definitely use Knowledge even at the $25/user/month tier, but there may be less expensive options, so you may want to talk to your Account Executive if you're interested.

If everyone who's involved already has a license, just turn it on and you can start using it immediately. All of the necessary information to configure this is in [the first link](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.knowledge_whatis.htm&type=5).

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox. I look upto you. But my question was around general framework of knowledge mobilisation across my company. I think articles alone would not cut it. I mean there are people who have worked on various projects across different verticals how do you tap into them.

Comment: Yesterday I talked to a colleague and he happened to work on a very elegant Email/SMS/Push archiving solution with Service and Marketing cloud. So it dawned on me that acrooss my company there would be so many elegant use cases and projects. In that case how do you cross train and create a knowledge cafe sorts so that these knowledge don't remain in Siloes .

Comment: let's take you for an example @sfdcfox. If you worked for a company ,I would given my arm to learn from your experience over the period of years but it would not be just your articles instead real use cases from real projects .It would be like an 'Insights sprints' with sfdcfox. I am interested in creating one such framework.